# How to add structure and template for new journal article from my custom portlet?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

When a new journal article is dropped into the page,:

- I have to show a link "select design" in the journal article.
- When user click on the link it needs to open a popup.
- In that popup I have to show list of all templates.
- When any of template is selected, then for the journal article it has
  to append the structure Id and template Id( template which I have
  chosen).

This is my requirement( like when we drop the web-content display portlet into the page, on the on click of the add button, it will open a page and shows options choose structure, when we select the choose structure, it will append the structure id and template id associated with the structure id, to the journal article).

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Could you clarify: Do you want to _add_ a _new_ structure and template to the portal, do you want to _set_ a structure and template when creating a new article or do you want to _open a page_ where you can choose the structure and template for your new article?

Comment: It helps others to understand your question, if your edit your post instead of adding the information in a comment. And I think that this is not a question, but a work task. Could you explain, what you have tried so far? By the way, _append_ and _set_ are two different operations, you can't _append_ a structure or template to an existing article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer following code snippet to add structure and template to the web content in your custom portlet

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
                Long parentFolderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;
                DDMStructure ddmStructure=DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil.getDDMStructure(11515);
                DDMTemplate ddmTemplate=DDMTemplateLocalServiceUtil.getDDMTemplate(11517);
                Map<Locale,String> titleMap=new HashMap<Locale,String>();
                titleMap.put(themeDisplay.getLocale(), "First Record");
                String content=
                        "<root available-locales='en_US' default-locale='en_US'>"
                                +"<dynamic-element dataType='string' indexType='keyword' name='Title' readOnly='false' repeatable='false' required='false' showLabel='true' type='text' width='small'>"
                                    +"<dynamic-content>FirstRecord</dynamic-content>"
                                +"</dynamic-element>"
                                +"<dynamic-element dataType='string' indexType='keyword' name='Description' readOnly='false' repeatable='false' required='false' showLabel='true' type='textarea' width='small'>"
                                +"  <dynamic-content>This the first one doing by programatically</dynamic-content>"
                                +"</dynamic-element>"
                                +"<dynamic-element dataType='image' fieldNamespace='wcm' indexType='keyword' name='DamImage' readOnly='false' repeatable='false' required='false' showLabel='true' type='wcm-image' width=''>"
                                +"  <dynamic-content>http://localhost:8080/documents/10184/0/welcome_community/0dc0adb1-b565-409a-b766-96d1e42b04fb?t=1459163274526</dynamic-content>"
                                +"</dynamic-element>"
                                +"<dynamic-element dataType='string' indexType='keyword' name='UserIdExcel' readOnly='false' repeatable='false' required='false' showLabel='true' type='text' width='small'>"
                                +"  <dynamic-content>458155</dynamic-content>"
                                +"</dynamic-element>"
                                +"<dynamic-element dataType='string' indexType='keyword' name='Username' readOnly='false' repeatable='false' required='false' showLabel='true' type='text' width='small'>"
                                +"  <dynamic-content>LaxmanDeepak</dynamic-content>"
                                +"</dynamic-element>"
                                +"<dynamic-element dataType='date' fieldNamespace='ddm' indexType='keyword' name='DateFromExcel' readOnly='false' repeatable='false' required='false' showLabel='true' type='ddm-date' width='small'>"
                                +"<dynamic-content>03/29/2016</dynamic-content>"
                                +"</dynamic-element>"
                            +"</root>";
                ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
                serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());
                serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH);

                JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.addArticle(themeDisplay.getUserId(), themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), parentFolderId, titleMap, null, content, ddmStructure.getStructureKey(), ddmTemplate.getTemplateKey(), serviceContext);
```